# Using variable with Scope Resolution Operator in PHP

Tags: php, oop, yii2, static-methods, scope-resolution

I am having a situation where, I have to use static method but here my class name is stored in some variable.

As per this link: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php#50310 I can not use variable with `::`.

for reference my code looks like below and I am using Yii2 for this stuff:

```
$modelName = "User";

$query = $modelName::find();
```

Obviously it is giving me error, Link I have given is 10 years old from now so Just wanted to check if is there any alternative to this situation.

**Update:**

```
$query = AdminUser::find(); // Works Fine

$name = 'AdminUser';
$query = call_user_func("$name::find");
// Giving Below Error
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'AdminUser' not found
```

Comment: According to this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), as of php 5.3 you can store the classname in a variable.  what is the error you are getting? Is the function you are calling defined as static?

Comment: @bryant yes I am calling the static method.

Comment: You couldn't in 2005, when the comment was written. What's your PHP version?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I am using 5.5.12

Comment: Then [it should work](http://3v4l.org/OsSMK). Can you please edit the question and paste the error message? Please use the clipboard to copy the actual error message, don't just describe it with your own words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify class name including namespace. See [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) about it. So your call should look like this:

```
$name = __NAMESPACE__ . '\AdminUser';
$query = call_user_func("$name::find");
```

Note that `__NAMESPACE__` constant returns current namespace. So if your `AdminUser` class belongs different namespace you need to specify it. E.g.:

```
//your current namespace:
namespace app\controllers;
//and somewhere in your method:
$name = 'common\models\AdminUser';
$query = call_user_func("$name::find");
```